# Find objects with same prop and return the update value with its associated prop

Tags: javascript, filter, foreach, sum, reduce

Consider this array of objects for example:

```
const arrSample = [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Container": "apple",
    "GiveUserId": 111,
    "RecieveUserId": 222,
    "Quantity": 10
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Container": "apple",
    "GiveUserId": 555,
    "RecieveUserId": 565,
    "Quantity": -5
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Container": "apple",
    "GiveUserId": 555,
    "RecieveUserId": 666,
    "Quantity": 20
  },
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Container": "orange",
    "GiveUserId": 555,
    "RecieveUserId": 565,
    "Quantity": 20
  }
]
```

I want to add the Quantity of same Container (for example apple) and return the properties of the one which has the higher Math.abs(arrSample.Quantity), meaning that between objects of id 1 and 2, the props of id 1 is returned while its quantity is changed to 10-5=5 and this trend continues which for this example the total Quantity = 25. This is the code that I have written but cannot get the required results:

```
 const holder = arrSample 
        .reduce((acc, value) => {
            const sameCont = acc.filter(item => item.Container === value.Container).pop() || {
                ...value,
                Quantity: 0,
            };
            sameCont.Quantity += value.Quantity;
            acc.push(sameCont);
            return acc;
        }, [])
```

Comment: I see only an Array, you forgot to add the code you're having issues with. please read [ask] and create a [mcve] of your issue. Also, your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: id 3 container apple has a larger quantity, so shouldn't that be returned with quantity 25? You have duplicate ids, probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thans for the comments, I have revised the description

Comment: First you find the element with the highest quantity:

`const highestQuantity = arrSample.reduce((a, b) => a.Quantity > b.Quantity ? a : b);`

Then accumulate all the quantities and store it in 'Quantity' property of the object:

`highestQuantity.Quantity = arrSample.reduce((a, b) => a + b.Quantity, 0);`

Use `highestQuantity` as you like.

Comment: Thanks, @Petyor for your comment, do you have any thought of how I first find similar Container and then follow your code?